# background image phonegap

Tags: javascript, css, image, cordova

I'm trying to adapt my background image to each screen but I'm don't exactly how to do.

I have a big image for the bigest screens but I'd like to resize the image for each screen size

Is there a way to do that ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `background-size` css property

```
background-size: 100% auto;
```